# How many constraints the 2D rigid body transformation matrix provide?

Tags: matrices, rotations, robotics

The 2D rigid body transformation matrix I'm concerned with is in **homogeneous representation**, hence the form:

\begin{bmatrix} 
\textbf{R} & \textbf{t} \\ 
0^T & 1
\end{bmatrix}

I know the **orthonormal constraints**: $$R^TR=1,$$ which contributes 3 constraints in the 2D case.

But does the **homogeneous representation** itself provide some constraints? And how many constraints does the translation vector $t$ provide?  Thus, the overall number of constraints is 6 in 2D case.

Answer (score 0):

The group of rigid transformations is called the special euclidean group and denoted by $\textrm{SE}(2)$ in 2D and $\textrm{SE}(3)$ in 3D.
This group is well known and is defined as follows:
$$ \textrm{SE}(2) := \biggr\{ 
\mathbf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{R} & \mathbf{t} \\ 
 \mathbf{0} & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
: \mathbf{R} \in \mathrm{SO}(2), \mathbf{t}\in \mathbb{R}^2 \biggr\}$$
$$ \textrm{SE}(3) := \biggr\{ 
\mathbf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{R} & \mathbf{t} \\ 
 \mathbf{0} & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
: \mathbf{R} \in \mathrm{SO}(3), \mathbf{t}\in \mathbb{R}^3 \biggr\}$$
where the group of rotations is called the special orthogonal group and denoted by $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ in 2D and $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ in 3D. The special orthogonal groups are defined as
$$ \textrm{SO}(2) := \bigr\{ 
\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} 
: \mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^T = \mathbf{1}, \det{\mathbf{R}} = +1 \bigr\}$$
$$ \textrm{SO}(3) := \bigr\{ 
\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} 
: \mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^T = \mathbf{1}, \det{\mathbf{R}} = +1 \bigr\}$$
where the determinant is positive because the group does not include reflective transformation. If we allow $\mathbf{R} = \pm 1$, then reflection are allowed, but I do not know if there is a name for this group.

To answer your question, no additional constraints exist beyond what is defined. Adding additional constraints would make a subgroup.